# how to disable rivafb while recompiling linux kernel (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, compiling

I'm newbie in linux and I want to install my graphics driver using [this Tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-i-fixed-my-display-resolution-by-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-489563052f6c) but I can't. (contents of `nvidia-installer.log` file below)

i did some researching and I found out that I need to recompile the linux kernel and disable rivafb (i have no idea what rivafb is) during compilation, but I don't know how to do that and i didn't found any Tutorial for this.

**contents of `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log`:**

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sat Sep 17 04:37:24 2022
installer version: 367.57

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface
-> Detected 2 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 2.
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 367.57.
-> An alternate method of installing the NVIDIA driver was detected. (This is usually a package provided by your distributor.) A driver installed via that method may integrate better with your system than a driver installed by nvidia-installer.

Please review the message provided by the maintainer of this alternate installation method and decide how to proceed:

The NVIDIA driver provided by Ubuntu can be installed by launching the "Software & Updates" application, and by selecting the NVIDIA driver from the "Additional Drivers" tab.


(Answer: Continue installation)
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: No)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="/usr/bin/cc".
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-47-generic/build'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-47-generic/build'
-> Performing rivafb check.
ERROR: Your kernel was configured to include rivafb support!

The rivafb driver conflicts with the NVIDIA driver, please
reconfigure your kernel and *disable* rivafb support, then
try installing the NVIDIA kernel module again.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

**output of `sudo lsmod | grep rivafb`:**

```
nothing!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally managed to do it myself, here's what I did:**

I followed [This Tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/build-linux-kernel) to build a kernel and in step 4.4 I disabled `nvidia riva support` in this location:

```
Main menu> Device Drivers > Graphical support > Frame buffer Device > Support for frame buffer devices > nVidia Riva support
```